# How to plot quantil band (in R)

Tags: java, r, plot, quantile

I have a CSV file which contains lines for each (Java GC) Event I am interested in. The object consists of a subsecond timestamp (non equidistant) and some variables. The object looks like this:

```
gcdata <- read.table("http://bernd.eckenfels.net/view/gc1001.ygc.csv",header=TRUE,sep=",", dec=".")
start = as.POSIXct(strptime("2012-01-01 00:00:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
gcdata.date = gcdata$Timestamp + start
gcdata = gcdata[,2:7] # remove old date col
gcdata=data.frame(date=gcdata.date,gcdata)
str(gcdata)
```

Results in

```
'data.frame':   2997 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ date           : POSIXct, format: "2012-01-01 00:00:06" "2012-01-01 00:00:06" "2012-01-01 00:00:18" ...
 $ Distance.s.    : num  0 0.165 11.289 9.029 11.161 ...
 $ YGUsedBefore.K.: int  1610619 20140726 20148325 20213304 20310849 20404772 20561918 21115577 21479211 21544930 ...
 $ YGUsedAfter.K. : int  7990 15589 80568 178113 272036 429182 982841 1346475 1412181 1355412 ...
 $ Promoted.K.    : int  0 0 0 0 8226 937 65429 71166 62548 143638 ...
 $ YGCapacity.K.  : int  22649280 22649280 22649280 22649280 22649280 22649280 22649280 22649280 22649280 22649280 ...
 $ Pause.s.       : num  0.0379 0.022 0.0287 0.0509 0.109 ...
```

In this case I care about the Pause time (in seconds). I want to plot a diagram, which will show me for each (wall clock) hour basically the mean as a line, the 2% and 98% as a grey corridor and the max value (within each hour) as a red line.

I have done some work, but using the q98 functions is ugly, having to use multiple lines statements seems to be wastefull, and I dont know how to achieve a grey area between q02 and q98:

```
q02 <- function(x, ...) {  x <- quantile(x,probs=c(0.2)) }
q98 <- function(x, ...) {  x <- quantile(x,probs=c(0.98)) }
hours = droplevels(cut(gcdata$date, breaks="hours")) # can I have 2 hours?
plot(aggregate(gcdata$Pause.s. ~ hours, data=gcdata, FUN=max),ylim=c(0,2), col="red", ylab="Pause(s)", xlab="Days") # Is always black?
lines(aggregate(gcdata$Pause.s. ~ hours, data=gcdata, FUN=q98),ylim=c(0,2), col="green")
lines(aggregate(gcdata$Pause.s. ~ hours, data=gcdata, FUN=q02),ylim=c(0,2), col="green")
lines(aggregate(gcdata$Pause.s. ~ hours, data=gcdata, FUN=mean),ylim=c(0,2), col="blue")
```

Now this results in a chart which has black dots as maximum, a blue line as the hourly average and a lower and upper 0,2 + 0,98 green line. I think it would be better readable to have a grey corridor, maybe a dashed maximum (red) line and somehow fix the axis labels.
[image: Exported Chart (png)]
Any suggestions? (the file is available above)

Comment: Removed the prompt for better cut+paste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

good to see fellow Debian old-timers here :)   Your answer is already pretty nice.  As I happen to work a lot with time series, I thought I'd throw in a variant using the excellent [zoo](http://cran.r-project.org/package=zoo) and [xts](http://cran.r-project.org/package=xts) packages. The latter builds on top of the former and has, among other things, the `period.apply()` function we can use here along with the `endpoints()` function to get you two-hourly aggregates.

So at the top I'd use

```
library(zoo)                                # for zoo objects
library(xts)                                # for period.apply

gcdata <- read.table("http://bernd.eckenfels.net/view/gc1001.ygc.csv",
                     header=TRUE, sep=",", dec=".")
timestamps <- gcdata$Timestamp + 
              as.POSIXct(strptime("2012-01-01 00:00:00", 
                         format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
gcdatazoo <- zoo(gcdata[-1], order.by=timestamps)    # as zoo object
```

to create a `zoo` object. Your function remains:

```
plotAreaCorridor <- function(x, y, col.poly1="lightgray", col.poly2="gray",...) {
    x.pol <- c(x, rev(x), x[1])
    y.pol <- c(y[,1], rev(y[,5]),y[,1][1])
    plot(x, y[,6]+1, type="n", ...) 
    polygon(x.pol, y.pol, col=col.poly1, lty=0)

    x.pol <- c(x, rev(x), x[1])
    y.pol <- c(y[,2], rev(y[,4]), y[,1][1])
    polygon(x.pol, y.pol, col=col.poly2, lty=0)

    lines(x, y[,3], col="blue") # median
    lines(x, y[,6], col="red")  # max

    invisible(NULL)
}
```

And we can then simplify a little:

```
agg <- period.apply(gcdatazoo[,"Pause.s."],               # to which data
                    INDEX=endpoints(gcdatazoo, "hours", k=2), # every 2 hours
                    FUN=function(x) quantile(x,               # what fun.
                                             probs=c(5,20,50,80,95,100)/100)) 

#v99 = q99(gcdata$Pause.s.)        # what is q99 ?
v99 <- mean(agg[,5])                  # mean of 95-th percentile?
plotAreaCorridor(index(agg),          # use time index as x axis
                 coredata(agg),       # and matrix part of zoo object as data
                 ylim=c(0,max(agg[,5])*1.5),
                 ylab="Quantiles of GC events",
                 main="NewPar Collection Activity")
abline(h=median(gcdatazoo[,"Pause.s."]), col="lightblue")
abline(h=v99, col="grey")
labeltxt <- paste("99%=",round(v99,digits=3),"s n=", nrow(gcdatazoo),sep="")
text(x=index(agg)[20], y=1.5*v99, labeltxt, col="grey", pos=3)  # or legend()
```

which gives

[image]

The axis is now automatic and shows weekdays only as the span is less than week; this can be override as needed.

Comment: Cool, danke Dirk (q99 was the 99th percentile)

Answer (score 4):

You have to try `polygon`. This code can be useful:

```
y98 = aggregate(gcdata$Pause.s. ~ hours, data=gcdata, FUN=q98)
y02 = aggregate(gcdata$Pause.s. ~ hours, data=gcdata, FUN=q02)
ymax = aggregate(gcdata$Pause.s. ~ hours, data=gcdata, FUN=max)
ymin = aggregate(gcdata$Pause.s. ~ hours, data=gcdata, FUN=min)
ymean = aggregate(gcdata$Pause.s. ~ hours, data=gcdata, FUN=mean)

x = ymean[,1]
y1 = cbind(y02[,2], ymean[,2], y98[,2])
y2 = cbind(ymin[,2], ymean[,2], ymax[,2])

plotAreaCI(x,y2, ylim=c(0,2), xlab="time", ylab="variable")
plotAreaCI(x,y1, ylim=c(0,2), poly.col="blue", add=TRUE)
```

[image: pic1]

or

```
plotAreaCI(x,y2, ylim=c(0,2), xlab="time", ylab="variable", nice.x = TRUE)
plotAreaCI(x,y1, ylim=c(0,2), mean.lwd=2, poly.col="blue", add=TRUE)
```

[image: pic2]

where the function `plotAreaCI` is defined by:

```
plotAreaCI = function(x, y, add=FALSE, nice.x = FALSE,
                          xlim=NULL, ylim=NULL,
                          mean.col="black", mean.lwd=1.5,
                          poly.col="gray", poly.lty=3,
                          xlab=NULL, ylab=NULL, main="",
                          ...) {
      isFactorX = isClass("factor", x)
      if(isFactorX) {
        x.label = x
        x = as.numeric(x)
      }
      if(is.null(xlim)) xlim=range(x, na.rm=TRUE)
      if(is.null(ylim)) ylim=range(y, na.rm=TRUE)
      x.pol = c(x, rev(x), x[1])
      y.pol = c(y[,1], rev(y[,3]), y[,1][3])
      if(!add) {
        plot.new()
        plot.window(xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim, ...)
        if(!nice.x & isFactorX) {
          axis(1, at=x, labels=x.label)
        } else {
          xticks = axTicks(1)
          if(isFactorX) {
            xticks = xticks[xticks>=1]
            axis(1, at=xticks, labels=x.label[xticks])
          } else {
            axis(1)
          }
        }
            axis(2, las=1)
        box()
        title(xlab=xlab, ylab=ylab, main=main)
      }
      polygon(x.pol, y.pol, col=poly.col, lty=poly.lty)
      lines(x, y[,2], col=mean.col, lwd=mean.lwd)
      return(invisible())
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, works great. I guess the plot(type="n") is mainly needed to pass the variable arguments (for specifying x/ylab etc?).

Comment: Ok, according to this thread the type="n" in the plot() does not work, cause it is processing a factor. I somewhat need a way to work around it. Besides that I have now a 2 shades corridor, max and mean lines with your help, this is fine. http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/plot-ignores-type-quot-n-quot-when-x-is-factor-PR-13703-td923777.html

Comment: I didn't sea 'x' was a factor, I'm editing the code and adding some ad hoc solutions.

Comment: I think the 'x' axis is-not-really a factor, and that's why this kind of graph is approapiate, but found a solution converting factor to numeric and back. And the plot(type="n"), I'm not using that anynmore, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is code I use to plot temporal variation in laboratory analytes (systolic blood pressure in this instance):

```
 SBP.qtr.mat <- aggregate(set1HLI$SBP, 
                          list(  year(set1HLI$Drawdt)+0.25* quarter(set1HLI$Drawdt)), 
                           quantile, prob=c(0.1,0.25,0.5,0.75, 0.9,0.95, 0.975), na.rm=TRUE)
 matplot(SBP.qtr.mat[,1], SBP.qtr.mat$x, type="pl")
```

Shouldn't be too hard to adapt that to your problem.... or you could post a reproducible example to work with. This give the 10th, 25th, 50th, 75th, 90th, 95th and 97.5th percentiles in a single data.frame and matplot handles the plotting of such an object.

The grey area?, ... The usual approach is to plot a polygon going out on the lower bounds, "turning" at the right extreme and coming back on the high side, and connecting back at the left-hand side. The `polygon` arguments are set up as `x, y`. There is a `col` argument you would set to "grey".

To make '2 hour' sequences to which you could merge your dataframe or use with`cut.POSIXt" as a breaks argument , there is the option of using multiples of time units with`seq.POSIXt`:

```
> seq(ISOdate(1910,1,1), ISOdate(1999,1,1), "10 years")
[1] "1910-01-01 12:00:00 GMT" "1920-01-01 12:00:00 GMT" "1930-01-01 12:00:00 GMT" "1940-01-01 12:00:00 GMT"
[5] "1950-01-01 12:00:00 GMT" "1960-01-01 12:00:00 GMT" "1970-01-01 12:00:00 GMT" "1980-01-01 12:00:00 GMT"
[9] "1990-01-01 12:00:00 GMT"
```

I didn't see it documented but you can use multiples of interval with `cut.POSIXt`:

```
> str( cut( seq(ISOdate(1910,1,1), ISOdate(1999,1,1), "years"), "10 years") )
 Factor w/ 9 levels "1910-01-01","1920-01-01",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
> str( cut( seq(ISOdate(1910,1,1), ISOdate(1999,1,1), "years"), "5 years") )
 Factor w/ 18 levels "1910-01-01","1915-01-01",..: 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 ...
```

Comment: the example is reproducible, isnt it?

Comment: I guess it is. I didn't recognize that at first. You can use my comments on time to fix Ricardo's code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not currently arrived at the following script (still need to look at the more advanced answer from DWin). It now somewhat looks like I was looking for, but the code is still pretty ugly (For example I dont know how to align the label and how to get proper xlab labels):

```
plotAreaCorridor = function(x, y, col.poly1="lightgray", col.poly2="gray",...) {
   x.pol = c(x, rev(x), x[1])
   y.pol = c(y[,1], rev(y[,5]),y[,1][1])
   plot(x, y[,6]+1, type="n", ...) # ugly since type="n" does not work for factor
   polygon(x.pol, y.pol, col=col.poly1, lty=0)

   x.pol = c(x, rev(x), x[1])
   y.pol = c(y[,2], rev(y[,4]), y[,1][1])
   polygon(x.pol, y.pol, col=col.poly2, lty=0)

   lines(x, y[,3], col="blue") # median
   lines(x, y[,6], col="red")  # max

   return(invisible())
}
pause = gcdata$Pause.s.
hours = droplevels(cut(gcdata$date, breaks="hours")) # can I have 2 hours?
agg = aggregate(pause ~ hours, FUN=quantile, probs=c(5,20,50,80,95,100)/100)
x = agg$hours
ys = agg$pause
q99 <- function(x, ...) {  x <- quantile(x,probs=c(0.99)) }  
v99 = q99(gcdata$Pause.s.)
vmed = median(gcdata$Pause.s.)
plotAreaCorridor(x, ys,ylim=c(0,v99*1.5))
abline(h=vmed, col="lightblue")
abline(h=v99, col="grey")
label=paste("99%=",round(v99,digits=3),"s n=", length(gcdata$date),sep="")
text(x=30, y=v99, label, col="grey", pos=3)
title("NewPar Collection Activity")
```

[image: New Chart Version]